# How do I count all the lines of code in all headers and source files in a folder? *.cpp *.h

Tags: grep, command, source, header-file

Say I have a project folder containing a number of header and source files for c++;
How would I count the total number of lines of all of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wc` command with option `-l` prints the line count of each file and a total if multiple files are given as input.

Say I have two files `foo.cpp` and `bar.h` with 10 lines each, then `wc -l` gives this result:

```
$ wc -l *.cpp *.h
10 foo.cpp
10 bar.h
20 total
```

If you only need the total value, you could `cat` the files and pipe the result to `wc -l`:

```
$ cat *.cpp *.h | wc -l
20
```